# Writing to a specific spot in a text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a properties file config.properties which another program will be using and has to be in the format:

```
#Comment
property1=value1

#Comment
property2=value2

#Comment
property3=value3
```

My program in Matlab needs to modify value2 without changing the rest of the file. I am hoping that there is a way to search for property2 and just overwrite the number after the "=" but I can't find anything about how to write to a preexisting file in a specific location when there are no delimiters in the file.

My question is: How do I change value2 without changing the rest of the file?

Note: The Matlab code will be accessing and changing value2 multiple times while running so the only time the position is not known will be the first time. The file must be closed after each change to allow for access by the other program.

Comment: The straightforward way to do this is to read the file line-by-line, write it out line-by-line to a new file, and change the line(s) you want to edit.  If you want you could then delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file's name.  On many systems the idea of editing a file in-place is not really well defined.

Comment: Is there a way which has less overhead? I will be changing this specific value a lot during a test I'm running which will take a large amount of time to run.

Comment: @user3715487 If that's the case then you'd be far better off adjusting the way your programs are written. Either pregenerate all of the config files you need or modify your other program to accept multiple inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really clunky solution but it works.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');

prop_to_change = 'property2';
newvalue = 'new value';

% Find the PV pair to change
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    temp = strsplit(tline,'='); % Split the PV Pair into 2 cells
    if strcmp(temp{1},prop_to_change)
        newline = strrep(tline,temp{2},newvalue);
        frewind(fid); % Go back to start of the file
        fulltext = fread(fid,'*char')'; % Grab entire file prior to discarding
        fclose(fid);
        fid = fopen('test.txt','w'); % Loading with write flag discards the file contents
        fulltext = strrep(fulltext,tline,newline); % Replace PV pair
        fprintf(fid,'%s',fulltext); % Write modified text back to file
        fclose(fid);
        break
    end
end
```

test.txt now reads:

```
#Comment
property1=value1

#Comment
property2=new value

#Comment
property3=value3
```

Reading individual lines and then reading in the whole thing seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead. I chose to do it this way because I couldn't think of a simpler way to pull the PV pair without explicitly knowing the existing value. This can likely be done much better using regular expressions but I have very little understanding on how to get those to work.

Comment: This helped a lot. All I needed to do was find the first value that value2 was at and every other time I modify the config file using the stored previous value. Saves on the overhead. Thanks!